# Migrating User Stories From One TFS Server To Another In Excel

Tags: excel, tfs

I want to pull a set of user stories from a SOURCE TFS instance and put them into a TARGET TFS instance using Excel.  I know other people have done this!

However, once I download the stories into Excel, I cannot rebind the spreadsheet to the TARGET TFS instance.  I keep getting the following:

> "The reconnect operation failed because the team project collection
>   you selected does not host the team project the document references."

And, I dont see a way to clear the ID for the story or edit the document project/server references.

**Q: How do I Migrate User Stories From One TFS Server To Another In Excel?**

This should be easy!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create another excel sheet with the same columns that is bound to the new TFS server.

Then just copy and paste between them.

Comment: DUH!  Why didnt I think of that?  Hahahahaha...now that is almost embarrassing :)

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be easier to use the TFS API to read from one instance and copy them to another TFS instance.  The following post provides an example:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bryang/2011/09/07/copying-tfs-work-items/